# User modeling in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

I would like to build a rails application in which users of the site have their own portfolio of mp3 files that that they can share with other users. How would I go about modeling the user? User has_one  portfolio; User has_many :files through :portfolio? etc.  Thank you for input

Comment: Yes, exactly that. `User has_one :portfolio`, `Portfolio has_many :files`, `User has_many :files, through: :portfolio`.

Comment: What do you mean with "have their OWN portfolio", and what do you mean with "that they can SHARE with other users"? By modeling this with has_one, you won't have an OWN portfolio anymore...  (who's the owner - the original creator, or the one sharing it?)

Comment: Expect to hear jackboots, creaking leather and poorly muffled screams when the RIAA send round a few boys to have a 'chat'